# Handling keyboard shortcuts for webapp

Tags: javascript

Please review the code.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { // shortcuts
  if (e.ctrlKey) { // Ctrl+
    if (/^(82|79|83|66|191)$/.test(e.keyCode)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 82: // R
        newDoc();
        break;
      case 79: // O
        openDoc();
        break;
      case 83: // S
        saveDoc();
        break;
      case 66: // B
        showHideStatusBar(statusBarOn ? false : true); // toggle
        break;
      case 191: // /
        alert("Welcome to " + appname + "!");
        break;
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 9) { // tab
    e.preventDefault();
    var sStart = textarea.selectionStart,
      text = textarea.value;
    textarea.value = text.substring(0, sStart) + "\t" + text.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
    textarea.selectionEnd = sStart + 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the background/usage of your app? On what basis you want to review your code? readability/clean-code/optimization? Please mention them.

Comment: optimization and simplifying mainly...
it is for a text-editing webapp..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS, when you have a switch, it's usually better to go with a dispatch table.

```
var mapping = {
    82: newDoc,
    79: openDoc,
    83: saveDoc,
    66: function() {
        showHideStatusBar(statusBarOn ? false : true);
    },
    191: function() {
        alert("Welcome to " + appname + "!");
    }
};
mapping[e.keyCode]();
```

Or if you don't want to give a name:

```
({
    82: newDoc,
    79: openDoc,
    83: saveDoc,
    66: function() {
        showHideStatusBar(statusBarOn ? false : true);
    },
    191: function() {
        alert("Welcome to " + appname + "!");
    }
})[e.keyCode]();
```

Also, use `===` instead of `==` for multiple reasons. Google "triple equal javascript" if you want more information.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use a *dispatch table* instead of a *switch*. However, you have to handle a default case during lookup, something like `var fn = mapping[e.keyCode]; if (fn !== undefined) { fn() } else { default() }`

Comment: There is no default case in his code.

Comment: Except there is an `if` preventing this :)

Comment: /me crawls back in shame for not reading the code carefully… thanks.